# Best way to import libraries in angular2 using typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm playing with Angular2 and I need to use jQuery.

I downloaded the d.ts file and then I referenced the definitions using this syntax at the top of each file

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

This works, but I have 2 questions:

1. It is really needed to use that syntax in **each** file? (not very funny)
2. Is that the correct syntax? In angular2 (typescript) we use something like: `import {RouteConfig, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';`
   So, what is the difference? What is the best?

Comment: you shouldn't have to use the /// reference if you have a tsconfig.json configuring your project.

Comment: the reference declarations are for the **compiler** to know what files it should compile. the import statements are compiled to **runtime** module imports that the module loader can use to load your application. you can use tsconfig.json to configure what files should be compiled and you will no longer need the reference statements in all the files, the import statements will be enough.

Comment: that's probably better as an answer..

Comment: oh as for the difference. the /// reference is typescript specific, while import is the ES6 standard. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two statements do different things.

1. **reference** is used to tell the **compiler** what files it should include when compiling.

It is indeed cumbersome to always have **reference** statements in your files. That's why it is possible to use a **tsconfig.json** file that will tell the compiler what it should include instead.

You can generate one using the command:

```
tsc --init
```

An example of a **tsconfig.json** content would be:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

2. **import {X} from 'y'** is used to define module dependencies at **runtime**.

Is the ES6 standard import statement.

In TypeScript it will get compiled to Javascript that will tell the module loader what the dependencies are at **runtime** so it can go fetch them.

For example if the module is **commonjs** this TypeScript code:

```js
import {doSomething} from './moduleTree';

doSomething()
```

Gets compiled to:

```js
"use strict";
var moduleTree_1 = require('./moduleTree');
moduleTree_1.doSomething();
```

In conclusion, **reference** is used at compile time and **import** is used at runtime.

Comment: Just a question: Why I can specify just 'angular2/router' and not the complete path?

Comment: I think that's because modules found in the node_modules folder is automatically considered to be an ambient external module (you can check more on that in the handbook http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries)